# Bulk Upload from Fileshare to SP 2010 with Metadata

Tags: file-upload, file-metadata

What are my immediate options (free tool) in order to bulk upload files with metadata? I have found followings but none satisfy the bulk-load requirements.

For example: 
CodePlex: 
http://spbulkdocumentimport.codeplex.com/ Seems like meta-data not supported
http://docuploadmetadata.codeplex.com/ - not sure if its still a good download b/c low traffic, no documentation, author deleted source code, no comments...

Comment: Powershell: 
http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/bulk-upload-files-with-metadata-into.html - Does not support Data/Time fields

Free Tool:
http://roxority.com/uploadzen-documentation/better-sharepoint-bulk-file-uploads-with-uploadzen.html - Looks like no meta-data support...

Answer (score 2):

There's a post by Paul Childs that'll help - [Bulk upload files with metadata into SharePoint using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/bulk-upload-files-with-metadata-into.html)

Comment: Thanks but Paul's script does not support Date/Time type fields.

Answer (score 0):

Roxanne,

Are you still waiting for an answer? I have very exact situation and I think I am going to use DocKit from Vyapin (a 30 day trial) to bulk upload in Dev environment. If I can convince my boss then I can get him to purchase the license for production.

But I would like to get hold of a PowerShell that will do this. Anyone else... This is a hot topic.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://spfileupload.codeplex.com/) script as a base for my own - especially for handling metadata columns. It's very well commented.